# error: ‘visualization_msgs::Marker’ has no member named ‘set_points_size’

Tags: ros, marker, visualization-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i wrote fdisplay.cpp in src folder, when i run rosmake , i have error .

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/WrenchStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped.h>
#include <visualization_msgs/Marker.h>

class Transforms{
public:
    Transforms();
    void f1Callback(const geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped&);
    void f2Callback(const geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped&);
    void DrawFn(int,char*,geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped,int);

    geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped f1ft,f2ft;
    geometry_msgs::PointStamped f1cl,f2cl;
    geometry_msgs::PointStamped start;

    ros::NodeHandle node;
    tf::TransformListener listener;
    ros::Subscriber f1_sub,f2_sub;
    ros::Publisher marker_pub;
    visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
private:

};

Transforms::Transforms(){
    marker_pub = node.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("fmarker", 10);
    start.point.x=0;
    start.point.y=0;
    start.point.z=0;

}
void Transforms::DrawFn(int id,char* frame, geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped vector,int color){
    marker.header.frame_id = frame;
    marker.header.stamp = ros::Time();
    marker.ns = "my_namespace";
    marker.id = id;
    marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW;
    marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD;
    marker.pose.position.x = 0;
    marker.pose.position.y = 0;
    marker.pose.position.z = 0;
    marker.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
    marker.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
    marker.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
    marker.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
    marker.scale.x = 0.008;
    marker.scale.y = 0.02;
    marker.scale.z = 0.0;
    marker.color.a = 1.0;
    marker.color.r = 1.0;
    marker.color.g = 0.0;
    marker.color.b = 0.0;
    marker.set_points_size(2);
    marker.points[0].x=(start.point.x)/1000;
    marker.points[0].y=(start.point.y)/1000;
    marker.points[0].z=(start.point.z)/1000;
    marker.points[1].x=start.point.x/1000+vector.vector.x/100;
    marker.points[1].y=start.point.y/1000+vector.vector.y/100;
    marker.points[1].z=start.point.z/1000+vector.vector.z/100;

    marker_pub.publish(marker);

}

void Transforms::f1Callback(const geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped& msg){
    f1ft.vector=msg.wrench.force;
}


void Transforms::f2Callback(const geometry_msgs::WrenchStamped& msg){
    f2ft.vector=msg.wrench.force;
}



int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "forcesdisplay");


    Transforms Trans;

    Trans.f1_sub=Trans.node.subscribe("finger1/nano17ft",1000,&Transforms::f1Callback,&Trans);
        Trans.f2_sub=Trans.node.subscribe("finger2/nano17ft",1000,&Transforms::f2Callback,&Trans);

    ros::Rate rate(10.0);
    ros::Time now;
    geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped wvect,weight,weight1;

    tf::Vector3 weight2;
    tf::Transformer TransClass;
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    tf::Stamped<tf::Vector3> vaux,w2;


    while (Trans.node.ok()){


        Trans.DrawFn(1,"/BHand/FingerOne/Sensor",Trans.f1ft,1);
        Trans.DrawFn(2,"/BHand/FingerTwo/Sensor",Trans.f2ft,1);




        //DRAW WEIGHT:

        //FINGER 1
        tf::vector3StampedMsgToTF(Trans.f1ft,vaux);

        try{
            now = ros::Time::now();
            vaux.frame_id_="/BHand/FingerOne/Sensor";
            vaux.stamp_=now;

            Trans.listener.waitForTransform("/BHand/FingerOne/Sensor", "/robot_base",   now, ros::Duration(3.0));
            Trans.listener.lookupTransform("/BHand/FingerOne/Sensor", "/robot_base",now/*ros::Time(0)*/, transform);
            Trans.listener.transformVector("/robot_base",vaux,w2);
            tf::vector3TFToMsg(w2,wvect.vector);

            weight=wvect;

    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex){
            ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
        }
        try{

            //FINGER 2
            tf::vector3StampedMsgToTF(Trans.f2ft,vaux);
            now = ros::Time::now();
            vaux.frame_id_="/BHand/FingerTwo/Sensor";
            vaux.stamp_=now;

            Trans.listener.waitForTransform("/BHand/FingerTwo/Sensor", "/robot_base",now, ros::Duration(3.0));
            Trans.listener.lookupTransform("/BHand/FingerTwo/Sensor", "/robot_base",now, transform);
            Trans.listener.transformVector("/robot_base",vaux,w2);
            tf::vector3TFToMsg(w2,wvect.vector);

            weight.vector.x=weight.vector.x+wvect.vector.x;
            weight.vector.y=weight.vector.y+wvect.vector.y;
            weight.vector.z=weight.vector.z+wvect.vector.z;

            Trans.DrawFn(5,"/robot_base",weight,3);
            printf("Weight:%f %f %f = %f\n",weight.vector.x,weight.vector.y,weight.vector.z,sqrt(weight.vector.x*weight.vector.x+weight.vector.y*weight.vector.y+weight.vector.z*weight.vector.z));
        }
        catch (tf::TransformException ex){
            ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
        }

        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
};
```

error :

```
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  Scanning dependencies of target fdisplay
  [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fdisplay.dir/src/fdisplay.cpp.o
  /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws6/src/tf_workshop/src/fdisplay.cpp: In member function ‘void Transforms::DrawFn(int, char*, geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped, int)’:
  /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws6/src/tf_workshop/src/fdisplay.cpp:62:9: error: ‘visualization_msgs::Marker’ has no member named ‘set_points_size’
    marker.set_points_size(2);
           ^
  /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws6/src/tf_workshop/src/fdisplay.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
  /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws6/src/tf_workshop/src/fdisplay.cpp:107:56: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     Trans.DrawFn(1,"/BHand/FingerOne/Sensor",Trans.f1ft,1);
                                                          ^
  /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws6/src/tf_workshop/src/fdisplay.cpp:108:56: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     Trans.DrawFn(2,"/BHand/FingerTwo/Sensor",Trans.f2ft,1);
                                                          ^
  /home/zakizadeh/catkin_ws6/src/tf_workshop/src/fdisplay.cpp:151:41: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
      Trans.DrawFn(5,"/robot_base",weight,3);
                                           ^
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fdisplay.dir/src/fdisplay.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fdisplay.dir/all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256190/error:-%E2%80%98visualization_msgs::marker%E2%80%99-has-no-member-named-%E2%80%98set_points_size%E2%80%99/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-05**:
This compiler error is trying to tell you that the `set_points_size` method doesn't exist on a `visualization_msgs::Marker` object.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-03-05**:
what can i do ?? i need points_size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you don't need `points_size` . You need to set the size of the `points` vector within the `marker` object. Since `points` is a `std::vector`, I would start with the [std::vector documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

From the `std::vector` documentation, you should look for a method that sets the size of the vector, and you should find the [resize method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). Now you know that the proper way to set the size of `marker.points` is `marker.points.resize(2)`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-03-06**:
thanks a lot .